# Как подсчитать одинаковые имена в mysql и вывести колличество?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: таблица]

Для примера есть код который выводит последние добавленные оценки.

```
$limit = $limit ? intval($limit) : "20";

if (!$r_short) {
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_logs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,{$limit}");

while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) { 
    $r_short .= "<div class=\"ratefull\">{$row['member']} <span>оценка {$row['rate']}</span></div>";
}

}
echo $r_short;
```

Нужно вывести кто и сколько оценок поставил?
Т.е нужно подсчитать сколько одинаковых имен в колонке **member** и отсортировать по убыванию(**noname**, это гости их считать не нужно).

*Например:*

admin  -  100 оценок

admin2 -  50 оценок

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db->query("SELECT member, count(*) as rates 
            FROM " . PREFIX . "_logs 
            WHERE member <> 'noname' 
            GROUP BY member 
            ORDER BY rates"
          );
```

Comment: Как пронумеровать это всё дело? `1 admin - 100оц ... 2 admin`

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT member,  
       count(member) as cnt, 
       sum(rate) as s_rate 
FROM <tablename>  
WHERE member!='noname' 
GROUP BY member 
ORDER BY cnt;
```